# python tuple of tuples, if a subtuple has the same first subelement as another, keep one (irrelevant which) and delete the rest

Tags: python, tuples

I have a following format tuple:

```
((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))
```

I need to have a tuple in the end, where the first element of every sub tuple is unique, i.e:

```
((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617))
```

Up to now i have been doing exhaustive search but this is extremely inefficient.

The list is ordered by first element and i dont care about the order of the list after manipulation
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the input ordered by the first element, and do you care about the order of the output?

Comment: @DeepSpaceThe list is ordered by first element and i dont care about the order of the list after manipulation

Comment: This is not a list but it is a tuple

Comment: @zamir   I have tried exhaustive search. 
It might be a tuple, you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dict.items()` to keep the last instance set:

```
data = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

>>> tuple(sorted(dict(data).items()))
((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 631))
```

Comment: great answer, works even if the input is not ordered at all (although it totally dependent on how `dict(iterable_of_tuples)` works)

Comment: `sorted` is somewhat superfluous…

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the input is already ordered by the first element and you don't care doing some `import`s to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

inp = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

output = []
for group, elements in itertools.groupby(inp, key=itemgetter(0)):
    output.append(next(elements))
```

`output` is

```
[(624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617)]
```

As a list comprehension:

```
output = [next(elements) for group, elements in itertools.groupby(inp, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `set`.

**Ex:**

```
data = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

seen = set()
res = []
for i in data:
    if i[0] not in seen:
        seen.add(i[0])
        res.append(i)
print(tuple(res))
```

**Output:**

```
((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617))
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good usecase for `setdefault()`:

```
data = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

result = {}
for fst, snd in data:
    result.setdefault(fst, snd)

print(list(result.items()))
# [(624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using set + list comprehension

```
>>> x = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

>>> already_seen = set()
>>> [i for i in x if i[0] not in already_seen and not already_seen.add(i[0])]
```

Output:

```
[(624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617)]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can convert your data into a dict than you can include each key, value pair from the dict into a list:

```
data = ((624, 612), (625, 613), (626, 614), (627, 615), (628, 616), (629, 616), (630, 617), (630, 618), (630, 619), (630, 620), (630, 621), (630, 622), (630, 623), (630, 624), (630, 625), (630, 626), (630, 627), (630, 628), (630, 629), (630, 630), (630, 631))

print(list(dict(data).items()))
```

**output:**

```
[(624, 612),
 (625, 613),
 (626, 614),
 (627, 615),
 (628, 616),
 (629, 616),
 (630, 631)]
```